# Showing an Image using JavaFX, FXML and .setImage when a mouse button is clicked

Tags: java, imageview, javafx-8, fxml

I've created an ImageView within a HBox and I want to set the image when I double click on a ListView item. I've setup the ImageView FXML as such (explicitly setting the Image URL in the FXML works perfectly but i want to essentially import/set the image by softcoding it in the controller class as the image may change):

```
<HBox>
<ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitHeight="300" fitWidth="200">

</ImageView>
<ImageView fx:id="imageView1" fitHeight="300" fitWidth="200">

</ImageView>
</HBox>
```

Here is the Controller class. I've used .setImage and passed the Image File but it doesn't seem to show. Is the ImageView observable and will it change once there is an event? I've debugged it through and there is a pointer to the image so I believe it's being passed.

```
public class Controller {

private SortedList<ClickOption> sortedList;

@FXML
private ListView<ClickOption> optionsListView;

@FXML
private ImageView imageView;

public void initialize(){
    sortedList = new SortedList<ClickOption>(ClickOptionData.getInstance().getClickOptionList());
    optionsListView.setItems(sortedList);
}

@FXML
public void handleMouseClick(){
    optionsListView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                System.out.println("Mouse clicked twice");
                Image image = new Image("file:testImage.png");
                imageView.setImage(image);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Andy

Comment: Probably the path is wrong. You can check with, e.g. `File file = new File("testImage.png");` `System.out.println("file exists: "+file.exists());` `imageView.setImage(file.toURI().toString());`. For either this, or your code, to work, `testImage.png` would have to be in the current working directory (which is pretty much unknown except at development/testing time).

Comment: Thanks James. I've just checked it and the file doesn't exist. I'll see what I can do. Much appreciated with this.

Comment: This is working now James :) Nice one.